# Dynamic view creation

Tags: aurelia

I'm trying to get a simple dynamic view working the simplest possible way.

```
import {inject, noView, ViewCompiler, ViewSlot} from 'aurelia-framework';

@noView
@inject(ViewCompiler, ViewSlot)
export class ButtonVM{

    constructor(vc, vs){

        this.viewCompiler = vc;
        this.viewSlot = vs;


        var viewFactory =  this.viewCompiler.compile('<button>Some button</button>');
```

---

but apparantly I'm missing something, the view factory should be able to create a view and then it should be added to a viewslot?

What am I missing in the above code?

I should mention that I tried to follow Rob's comments in this thread: 
https://github.com/aurelia/templating/issues/35

Answer (score 3):

See the updated post by Rob in the same [thread](https://github.com/aurelia/templating/issues/35).

```
import {inject, noView, ViewCompiler, ViewSlot, Container, ViewResources} from 'aurelia-framework';

@noView
@inject(ViewCompiler, ViewSlot, Container, ViewResources)
export class Test {
    constructor(vc, vs, container, resources){
        this.viewCompiler = vc;
        this.viewSlot = vs;

        var viewFactory =  this.viewCompiler.compile('<button>${title}</button>', resources);
        var bindingContext = { title:'Click Me'};
        var view = viewFactory.create(container, bindingContext);
        this.viewSlot.add(view);
        this.viewSlot.attached();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I noticed it, not sure if that is enough though. As soon as I have tested it I will post the outcome here as well.

Answer (score 1):

Late for an answer but this can be easily achieved by using getViewStartegy method provided by aurelia.

```
export class Test {

 constructor(vc, vs, container, resources){
 }
 getViewStrategy() {
    return new InlineViewStrategy('<button>${title}</button>');
 }
}
```